# Как реализовать мультитач управление

Tags: unity3d

Есть код с поворотом камеры и управлением персонажем с помощью джойстика. По отдельности все прекрасно работает, но если осматриваться и ходить одновременно, то камера движется за пальцем который на джойстика (то есть если я сдвину джойстик вверх, пойду вперёд, то камера тоже повернется наверх)
Рейкаст вроде не работает с UI (а его аналогов для UI я не встречал), тем более канвас не привязан к камере
В общем кто знает как реализовать мультитач для такого случая?

Comment: Добавьте код к вопросу, так будет проще помочь.

Comment: Как вариант, проверяйте координаты тача, если в области джойстика, то камера не реагирует.

Answer (score 0):

У UI есть [EventSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/EventSystem.html) и интерфейсы для обработки ввода и рейкастов - [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html), [IPointerEnterHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html), [IDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html) и т.д. зависит от вашей реализации. Можете прямо на интерфейсе сделать зону джостика.

А вообще сам мультитач можно обрабатывать через получение количества и координаторов точек касания. Вот урок по [мультитачу](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/multi-touch-input)

Answer (score 0):

В Unity есть Asset - CrossPlatformInput. Там есть готовые решения.